# Entity lazy methods and Dimetra law

Tags: java, design-patterns, entity, design-principles

I have entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CARDS")
public class Card {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
  private Person person;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "card")
  private List<CardStatus> cardStatuses;
```

And I my service I can call next code:

```
public Card getCardBlaBlaBla(Long id){

   Card card  = cardRepository.findaCard(id);

   Something something = card.getCardStatuses().get(0).getSomething();
}
```

**card.getCardStatuses().get(0).getSomething()** - `getCardStatuses` is `LAZY`

My questions - Does this challenge violate the Dimetra law?

> The Law of Demeter There is a well-known heuristic called the Law of
>   Demeter2 that says a module should not know about the innards of the
>   objects it manipulates. As we saw in the last section, objects hide
>   their data and expose operations. This means that an object should not
>   expose its internal structure through accessors because to do so is to
>   expose, rather than to hide, its internal structure. More precisely,
>   the Law of Demeter says that a method f of a class C should only call
>   the methods of these:
>
> ```
> • C
> • An object created by f
> • An object passed as an argument to f
> • An object held in an instance variable of C
> ```
>
> The method should not invoke methods on objects that are returned by
>   any of the allowed functions. In other words, talk to friends, not to
>   strangers. The following code appears to violate the Law of Demeter
>   (among other things) because it calls the getScratchDir() function on
>   the return value of getOptions() and then calls getAbsolutePath() on
>   the return value of getScratchDir(). final String outputDir =
>   ctxt.getOptions().getScratchDir().getAbsolutePath();

`Card` - is **data structures** and not violate the Dimetra law but `LAZY` methos has logik(make select to DB).

Does this challenge violate the Dimetra law or Not? If yes how can I use it correctly?

I realy have a lot of code like:

```
entityOblect.getChield().getChield().getSomething();
```

**EDIT**

From Cleand Code book:

[image]

**EDIT2**

(c) Robert C. Martin - Clean Code

> Active Record Active Records are special forms of DTOs. They are data
>   structures with public (or beanaccessed) variables; but they typically
>   have navigational methods like save and find. Typically these Active
>   Records are direct translations from database tables, or other data
>   sources. Unfortunately we often find that developers try to treat
>   these data structures as though they were objects by putting business
>   rule methods in them. This is awkward because it creates a hybrid
>   between a data structure and an object. The solution, of course, is to
>   treat the Active Record as a data structure and to create separate
>   objects that contain the business rules and that hide their internal
>   data (which are probably just instances of the Active Record).

Answer (score 1):

This violates the Demeter law :

```
Something something = card.getCardStatuses().get(0).getSomething();
```

In one statement, you navigate through all these objects :
`Card` -> `List<CardStatus>` -> `CardStatus` -> `Something`.

Ideally you should have this communication from the client side :
`Card` -> `Something`.

And in the `Card` class, the `Something` return could be implemented with a method doing this navigation :
`List<CardStatus>` -> `CardStatus` -> `Something`.

In a some way, the last one also violates the Demeter law but at a level that we could consider acceptable because we should not consider this relation `List<CardStatus>` -> `CardStatus` as a *stranger relation*.

It could give :

```
Something something = card.getSomethingOfCardStatuses(0);
```

or to avoid the *get* prefix :

```
Something something = card.findSomethingOfCardStatuses(0);
```

And `findSomethingOfCardStatuses()` could be defined in `Card` as :

```
public Something findSomethingOfCardStatuses(int statusNumber){
    // add some check for the index if required 
    // you could return Optional or an Exception according to your requirements
    return cardStatuses.get(0).getSomething();
}
```

I know that many developers like to dig manually in entity fields but personally I avoid doing that and I try to give them some logical methods with meaningful names and behaviors.   It makes core really clearer.

Comment: then what you said is the first thing I thought about. I totally agree. But. a Card is an entity. Create additional methods in the entity class - is this correct? I think that the entity should be a reflection of the table and no more. No?

Comment: You have generally two ways : dumb data model or clever data model. I always favor the second one. An entity may be both the representation in OOP of the relational table and a class that defines some logic. Why do you want to make these two aspects exclusive between them ?

Comment: I am eddit question. add fragment from book

Comment: I think that entity - is data structure and it can not have additional methods and beahavior. If I add some method to entity - it will Hybrid(data structure and object with behavior). I think that entity must be simple.

Comment: In the example, the author gives a bad use case where he refers to multiply the methods in the domain object. It is not your case. I think that the "hybrid structure" part  is really not clear about its boundaries and its risks.  For example :adding some helper methods in a data structure doesn't mean adding core logic in and should not create any issue in the design. Definitely, I prefer Martin Fowler explanations that are extremely clear about the domain model design. Here you will build an anemic domain model. : https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html

Comment: I eddit question again). Thank you for answer and link. I respect Robert C. Martin and Martin Fowler. But it seems to me in this matter they do not agree? or my English does not allow me to catch the whole thing?

Comment: oh yeah. for example I get the Java classes(JAXB) that were generated from XSD or WSDl - I can not add some methods for this class. But this classes sometimes has complex structure with a large nesting.

Comment: I know `Robert C. Martin`  but not in details what he wrote. I tried to read the clean code book. So yes the most of things that he told is right but these make part of good practices that are known by most of good and experienced developers. So I fast stopped the book. So I could not tell if your interpretation about the disagreement of the authors seems right. The question appears too broad finally.